# Broken SVG when importing to Figma

Tags: svg, figma

When dropping an SVG into a Figma canvas, the SVG object is broken, meaning it does not resemble the actual image. The SVG is exported from Adobe XD and is even tested with Microsoft Edge browser to work, meaning, the browser shows the correct image.

The image being imported contains:

- Shapes/Objects
- Images
- Texts
- and some blur effects from XD

What could be done so Figma can import SVG property?

Comment: And btw, the whole purpose of this is to import XD to Figma, which apparently there's no direct way to do it. So doing export XD to SVG and SVG to Figma is the best route.

Comment: My guess would be that the blur effects could be the problem since effects can often problematic. Try removing them.  Other than that, there may be some other kind of incompatibility, or perhaps lack of SVG standards support in one or both applications.